# Mac os x 10.13.4 macbook pro 13 2012 не видит внешний диск exfat

Tags: macos, usb, macbook

Не получается подключить внешний хард seagate 1tb под exfat к макбуку. Air под той же версией ОС видел его, ПК под Linux Mint видит и корректно монтирует.
В Disk Utility не отображается.
Гуглил, но подобной проблемы не нашел, везде пишут что OS X поддерживает exfat.
USB порт другую флешку под fat32 читает, стало быть порт исправен.
Буду благодарен если тот кто сталкивался и решил поделится информацией!

Comment: удалось решить проблему без форматирования диска?Такая же тема, хотелось бы сохранить инфу.

Answer (score 0):

Один из вариантов - вернуть формата диска [с помощью Linux обратно в NTFS](https://www.maketecheasier.com/how-to-reformat-an-external-hard-drive-to-ntfs-format-in-ubuntu-hardy/),
установить на Mac [Парагон](http://knowledge.seagate.com/articles/en_US/FAQ/006177en?language=en_US&key=ka03A000000Q0S4QAK&kb=n&wwwlocale=en-gb), чтобы он читал формат NTFS.

Другой вариант:
Изменить формат диска через сам Мак на [exfat](http://osxdaily.com/2016/08/30/erase-disk-command-line-mac/). После диск должен отобразиться в Finder